# Django Haystack - Spelling suggestion context variable not being set

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have everything properly configured for spelling suggestions in Haystack with Solr, but, when using the `SearchView`, the `suggestion` context variable does not get set. I have realized that this is due to https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/commit/8bf366b6781b22810696b18723da5902ce01e5b7:

```
if self.results and hasattr(self.results, 'query') and self.results.query.backend.include_spelling:
    context['suggestion'] = self.form.get_suggestion()
```

It appears here that the variable is set only if there are results, which clearly doesn't seem right. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may override the create_response of your SearchView (rolling back the patch you mentioned):

```
class MySearchView(SearchView):
    def create_response(self):
        (paginator, page) = self.build_page()

        context = {
            'query': self.query,
            'form': self.form,
            'page': page,
            'paginator': paginator,
            'suggestion': None,
        }

        if self.results.query.backend.include_spelling:
            context['suggestion'] = self.form.get_suggestion()

        context.update(self.extra_context())
        return render_to_response(self.template, context, context_instance=self.context_class(self.request))
```

Comment: This does work, but what is the reason behind the conditional in the `SearchView` code? Shouldn't a suggestion be shown specially when there are no results?

Comment: I believe the conditional was an excessive attempt to mitigate wrong suggestions to no-sense queries like "." but I agree with you, a suggestion should be provided.  However the only person who really knows why is the developer of Haystack :)

Comment: however providing no suggestion is just one possible behavior, thus the reason may be the developer would force you to override the create_response for special cases like this one: is up to you to decide if it's worth to providing a suggestion, which kind of suggestions and so on... just my two cents